# In what condition new mysql table should be created?

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

I am setting up database 
I have you tables "VENDOR" AND "CUSTOMER" 
both have addresses 
Should i create "ADDRESS" table differently for both "VENDOR" and "CUSTOMER"
or should i create one "ADDRESS" table and provide primary key of "ADDRESS" as a foreign key to both "VENDOR" and "CUSTOMER"

Comment: Address should be one table containing pure address data. Other entities will then just have a foreign key referencing Address table.

Comment: A better approach will be that table `Address` has a `foreignKey` for `Vendor` and `Customer`, this way you can have multiple addresses for one vendor or customer.

Comment: Depends on your use case. Is an address shared between multiple Customers and Vendors? Does a Customer have multiple addresses? Need to answer those sorts of questions before placement of FKs can be answered. You may even need a bridge table if it turns out to be many-to-many. But dont complicate if you dont need to.